# Macro expansion with colortbl and tabular

Tags: tables, colortbl

I would like to alternate row colors in a tabular environment. I found colortbl useful. To simplify writing, I built the following macros to alternate row colors (see MWE below). However, I cannot understand why the `\crc` macro cannot coexist with a `\multicolumn`, whereas `\rca` or `\rcb` work like a charm.

And, more important, how can I simplify writing such as I always use the same macro name to alternate colors, even when I'm using `\multicolumn`?

```
\documentclass {article}

    \usepackage {colortbl}

\begin {document}

% define row colors A and B
\def\rca{\rowcolor [rgb] {0.90, 0.95, 1.0}}
\def\rcb{\rowcolor [rgb] {0.80, 0.90, 1.0}}

% This one works like a charm
\begin {tabular} {|l|l|} \hline
    \rca \multicolumn {1} {|c|} {one} & 1 \\ \hline
    \rcb two & 2 \\ \hline
    \rca three & 3 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}

% use current row color and set color for next row
\def\cseta{\gdef\crc{\rca\csetb}}
\def\csetb{\gdef\crc{\rcb\cseta}}
\cseta          % (re)set \crc to the row color A

% This one does not want to compile!
% ! Misplaced \omit.
% \multispan ->\omit
%                   \@multispan
% l.23     \crc \multicolumn {1} {|c} {one}
%                                          & 1 \\ \hline
\begin {tabular} {|l|l|} \hline
    \crc \multicolumn {1} {|c} {one} & 1 \\ \hline
    \crc two & 2 \\ \hline
    \crc three & 3 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}

\end {document}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate. The problem is here that due to the inner \gdef you have a non-expandable command before the \multicolumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\multicolumn (and \rowcolor) wants to be the first thing in a cell. Some content before is possible but it must be expandable, and expand only to spaces.

You are using a \gdef before \multicolumn and this is not expandable and so won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand\CAred{\rowcolor{red}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\CBred{\rowcolor{red}}
\newcommand\CCred[1][]{\rowcolor{red}} 
\newcommand\CD{ } 
\newcommand\CE{\,} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\rowcolor{red}\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}\\ %work
\CAred\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}        \\ %work
%\CBred\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}       \\ %fails (robust command)
%\CCred\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}       \\ %fails (optional argument -> not expandable
\CD\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}           \\ %works
%\CE\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}          \\ %fails (content)
%\relax\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}       \\ %fails
%\def\xy{blub}\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}\\ %fails (definition)
%\parindent=10pt \multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}\\ %fails (assignment)
%blub\multicolumn{1}{r}{blub}         \\ %fails (content)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Do you have a clue to help me solve my problem (use the same macro name to alternate colors)?

Comment: Change the color at the end of the previous cell or in a \noalign.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer suggestion about `\noalign`, here is a working solution:

```
\documentclass {article}

    \usepackage {colortbl}

\begin {document}

% define row colors A and B
\def\rca{\rowcolor [rgb] {0.90, 0.95, 1.0}}
\def\rcb{\rowcolor [rgb] {0.80, 0.90, 1.0}}

\begin {tabular} {|l|l|} \hline
    \rca \multicolumn {1} {|c|} {one} & 1 \\ \hline
    \rcb two & 2 \\ \hline
    \rca three & 3 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}

% use current row color and set color for next row
\def\cseta{\noalign {\gdef\crc{\rca\csetb}}}
\def\csetb{\noalign {\gdef\crc{\rcb\cseta}}}
\gdef\crc{\rca\csetb}               % (re)set \crc to the row color A

\begin {tabular} {|l|l|} \hline
    \crc \multicolumn {1} {|c} {one} & 1 \\ \hline
    \crc two & 2 \\ \hline
    \crc three & 3 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}

\end {document}
```

Comment: In fact, the real solution to my problem with alternating colors was `\rowcolors` with the xcolor package (using `\usepackage [table] {xcolor}` or `\documentclass [xcolor=table] {beamer}`)